# What is the special character / escape for "whitespace" in a POSIX extented regular expression?

Tags: regex, posix-ere

I am new to this regular exp concept. I am trying to use this reg ex

```
[^@\s]+$
```

If i give the string as "abs", its actulally excluding the character 's' . which means '\s' is read as a character 's' rather than a whitespace. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please check if my edit is correct. I don't know if `.` is part of your regex, but I think it is likely not, so I removed it.

Comment: thank you. '.' was not part of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this POSIX equivalent:

```
^[^@[:space:]]+$
```

`[:space:]` matches any whitespace including newline. If you want to avoid matching newlines then use: `[:blank:]` instead.

Comment: Hi anubhava. does POSIX support unicode regular expression?

Comment: I believe it is not supported in POSIX, pls check here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: What does the @ symbol mean? I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: @GT77: There is no special meaning as `@` is just a literal `@` here. OP is also attempting same.

Answer (score 5):

The space character class in POSIX is `[:space:]`, so in your case, your regex would be:

```
[^@[:space:]]+$
```

Note that `[:space:]` can't standalone outside `[]` like `\d` or `\s` in other flavors. A space character class alone must be inside `[]`:

```
[[:space:]]
```